# Retrieve ParseUsers list in Java (Android)

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I have a table (ParseObject) called "Friends" with a "to" and "from" column  which use pointers to objectId's of User's. This table tracks who's friends with who, how do I create a query that will return all my friends as user objects - not just the ID stored in that table?

Thanks!

---

The ParseUser class often confuses me as it is clearly different from a ParseObject and can't be used with the same methods (like `ParseQuery.or`)

Currently, I'm trying:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> friendsFrom = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friends");
    friendsFrom.whereEqualTo("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> friendsTo = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friends");
    friendsTo.whereEqualTo("to", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    // where they've been accepted
    friendsFrom.whereEqualTo("accepted", true);
    friendsTo.whereEqualTo("accepted", true);

    // combine the queries - parse does this a 'special' way
    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> friends = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    friends.add(friendsFrom);
    friends.add(friendsTo);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> combinedQuery = ParseQuery.or(friends);
    combinedQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> friends, ParseException e) {
            if (friends != null) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Found " + friends.size() + " friends");
                contacts.clear();

                for (ParseObject friend : friends) {
                    //show user, or whatever you'd like to do..
                    }
                }
            });
```

But a ParseObject cannot be cast to a ParseUser so I can't do anything here..

### Update

According to Robert's advice I've tried the following, but it's still not providing me with the UserObjects I need - and for some reason, my Log aren't being written during these "findInBackground" callbacks by Parse..

```
        ParseQuery < ParseObject > friendshipAndUserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("friends");
    friendshipAndUserQuery.whereEqualTo("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    friendshipAndUserQuery.include("to");
    friendshipAndUserQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject friendship : objects) {
                UserObject friend = (UserObject) friendship.getParseObject("to");
                contacts.add(friend);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: in which table `accepted` held

Comment: dont point to User.objectId's in parse..  point to objects<User>. Its easier to get the object than the id anyway.   Then flatten your query for your list with 'query.incluce('pointerPropName')'

Comment: Hi kishore, accepted is in the "Friends" table.

Robert, can you please elaborate on how I avoid using an object ID as a pointer reference? I'm using that so if I need to switch to a less proprietary database down the track I don't have weird 'Parse lingo' everywhere like this "Object<User>" column you're describing.

Even still, how do I implement that and query it in full, I'm really bewildered by Parse' query system. Thanks!